# Umbraco 7.5.6 scheduled publish not working on production

Tags: .net, iis, umbraco

I have an Umbraco 7.5.6 site, for which Publish at/Unpublish at work just fine on local.

However when deployed to production, it's as if these events aren't even fired.

I've made sure the date formats and timezones are the same on my machine and on the server. Also made sure the database date format matches those.

Any ideas where I should be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this on a few servers, usually when the website can't resolve itself. The task that makes the call to unpublish/publish at accesses the site to call a controller action. If it can't access itself, the events never fire. This usually happens in more secure environments. You'll be able to see this by looking in the log files in the "/App_Data/Logs/" folder. There will a LOT of messages about the scheduled publishing task failing if this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the log4net logs in the app_data folder. Umbraco does scheduled http requests to itself for publishing. These requests can fail for multiple reasons and will show up in the log files.
A hostname url redirect using the IIS url rewrite module could be the issue.
I've also seen it fail when the umbracoUseSSL appsetting was not set to true for a site running on https.